# Android how to use control from other XML file

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android studio. I have `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java`, `secondactivity.xml` and `SecondActivity.java` for it.

I have a button control in `activity_main.java`.

I want to use that `button.click` event from `SecondActivity.java` **(not from MainActivity.java)**.

How can I use control of XML files other than that's particular JAVA file. I'm trying,

```
  Button but = (Button)  FindViewById(R.Layout.activity_main)
```

In `SecondActivity.java` file but I got failed, where am I wrong.  Please help.

Comment: Include your code, screenshots or layoutfile and logcat. This will help you get a quicker response. Also follow the How To Ask guide before posting a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If your question does not fit into the How To Ask guideline, you can try beginner programming forums and groups which will help you better than SO. If you've got precise technical problems with your code then post it on SO. If you do not follow the SO questions guideline your question might be downvoted or closed with no gain or response. You can edit your question and improve it, though.

Answer (score -2):

see in FindViewById you pass layout. activity file and you cast in button object that is not possible you try to pass button id